# SSL error when apache reverse proxied application is included via iframe

Tags: apache, iframe, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have a host behind a firewall and running a web application (app1) should include an iframe from another web application (https://www.example.com/app2) hosted on a second (internal) server.

What I want to do is configure the Apache hosting app1 to act as reverse proxy doing the following:

```
ProxyPass /app2 http://internal-ip-app2/app2
ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://internal-ip-app2/app2
```

I have only one DNS entry which is `www.example.com`
So, the URLs to the apps are:

```
https://www.example.com (app1)
https://www.example.com/app2 (app2)
```

Each of those works for itself, but not if included via iframe. This results in an SSL handshake error.

Any ideas on howto set this up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Ssl module (a2enmod ssl)
Then in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file include following lines

```
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ServerName localhost
    SSLProxyEngine On
    RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
```

Between  line

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
```

and line

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Hope it helps.